# Fixed Width Body but Different Header width

Tags: html, css

I have a body of fixed width as 980px; but I want my header and footer to have full width 100% of the window. Please suggest me how to do it.

```
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.header {
width: 100%;
}
```

I want header to ignore width of body.

Comment: Add your html and css and a fiddle with your code.

Comment: Percents look for the parent element for reference, which in this case is the body. Try using JS and setting width as width of the window. jQuery code is:  $('.header').width($(window).height());

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cjrJq try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with an additional container div instead. Like this:

HTML

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
   // do something here
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.footer {
   // do something here
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to declare `width:100%` as that is a `div`s default width. Also `position:relative` is not required on the container.

Comment: @Paulie_D True, I just picked up the 100% from the question and kept it. Relative is not required? Wow, I guess I never thought about it ... I picked it up at my early beginnings and used it since lol. Thanks for your comment though, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

usually done by another body set 100% and then create a wrapper with setting the width, etc.
try this code  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KhEtq)

**HTML**

```
    <body>
  <div class="header">
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
some text

    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.header {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Dear its again taking the width of 980px of wrappper. I want header to have 100% of the page width and rest of the body to have 980px. class header should bypass the class wrapperthan only we can achive this.

Comment: but nobody does and the body will take it that you specify the width is always 100%

Comment: Set your code specify another color white and you will see that when setting the width fixed you entire screen will be filled with the color you have chosen not specified width

Comment: @AlexWilson You might want to update you answer to conform with your Codepen. The HTML structure is different from that posted.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like below.

```
body {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.bodyContainer {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
}
```

and html structure is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>... </head>
    <body>
        <div class='header'>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContainer">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear its again taking the width of 980px of bodyContainer. I want header to have 100% of the page width and rest of the body to have 980px. class header should bypass the class bodyContainer than only we can achive this.

Answer (score 0):

first create a content wrapper and set a css from body to this wrapper, like this

```
#content_wrapper{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

now, set a header, footer out of wrapper.. and its will work fine ...

Answer (score 0):

As the .header is contained in the body, it seems a complicated approch.
I would put your content in  a container between header and footer and give this container a 980px fixed size.
This might be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/4vM8d/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="mainContent">
    <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```